# How to change angular ng-init attributewith jquery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, if-statement

so, I have a div with an image which I want to change for a gif when a specific scroll has occurred...

here is the html:

```
    <div class="col-xs-6 mitad" ng-init="varname='images/estandar/impresoraEstandarAnimada.gif'" id="seccion3B">
        <img ng-src="{{varname}}" id="gif">
    </div>
```

now, The idea is, to change the url in varname... I tried this but didn't work:

```
if ($(window).width() > 1700 && vistaEstandar.scrollTop > 1596 && vistaEstandar.scrollTop < 2490)
       {
            lore: 'url(../images/estandar/monitorVeloz1.gif)';
            $("#gif").attr("ng-src", "{{lore}}");
        }
```

any idea how to make it work?? I don't understand Angular very well (new at programming) and if I try to change it without Angular by just replacing the SRC attribute from the img tag, the gif loads the first time but if enter again in the if condition or if I refresh the website, it loads as static image

**UPDATED:**

all this js code is inside a controller already:

```
app.controller('estandarCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $routeParams, $location, $http, Data) 
{


$(document).ready(function(){
    // ----Clases para mantener los colores del header
    $(".navbar-header").addClass("fondoHeader");
    $("#fondoMenu").addClass("fondoHeader");
    $("#footer").removeClass("esconder");
    $("#social").removeClass("esconder");
    $(".navbar-brand").removeClass("esconder");
    $("#botonVideo").removeClass("fondoBoton");
    $("#vista").removeClass("barraVista");


    // ----Propiedades para los scrollbar
    var vistaEstandar = document.getElementById('vista');
    vistaEstandar.style.overflow= "auto";
    vistaEstandar.style.overflowX= "hidden";
    vistaEstandar.style.height = 100 + "%";
    $("#vista").smoothWheel();
    // ---animaciones para diferentes resoluciones
    vistaEstandar.onscroll = function() {animacionesEstandarVista()};
    function animacionesEstandarVista() 
    {

        if (($(window).width() > 1700 && vistaEstandar.scrollTop > 1596 && vistaEstandar.scrollTop < 2490) || ($(window).width() > 1700 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1596 && document.documentElement.scrollTop < 2490)){



        }
        else if (($(window).width() > 1700 && vistaEstandar.scrollTop > 3888 && vistaEstandar.scrollTop < 4286) || ($(window).width() > 1700 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 3888 && document.documentElement.scrollTop < 4286)) {
            document.getElementById("section6").style.background = "url(images/estandar/monitorEstandarEntrada.gif)";
            document.getElementById("section6").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
            document.getElementById("section6").style.backgroundPosition = "bottom";

        }
        else if (($(window).width() > 1700 && vistaEstandar.scrollTop > 4450) || ($(window).width() > 1700 && document.documentElement.scrollTop > 4450)) { 
            document.getElementById("section6").style.background = "url(images/estandar/monitorEstandarSalida.gif)";
            document.getElementById("section6").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
            document.getElementById("section6").style.backgroundPosition = "bottom";    
        }
        else
        {

        } 

});
});
```

so I already have a controller for the partial

Comment: where the piece of code is written?

Comment: Why are you using Angular? Can't you just change `src` attribute in `img`?

Comment: I can't for the reason I explained... when it changes... the gif doesn't work.... it only works as a gif the first time the page is opened... if it is reloaded it won't work. Now, the gif is just a one time loop gif

Comment: @Caro Check my answer and see if that does what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

On your html element aka your scroll use the ngChange directive and pass a function that will change your url variable:

HTML:

```
<!-- change scrollable element to whatever the scroll bar is on aka table... ect -->
<div>
    <scrollable-element ng-change="myChangeFunction()"></scrollable-element>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// inside your controller:
$scope.myChangeFunction = function() {
        var newUrl = '/some/image.img'
        $scope.varname = newUrl;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are suggesting is not optimal, but since you asked how to do it, here is the solution:

[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/humubevubi/edit?html,js,output)

The idea is that from jQuery, you have to set the `$scope` property and call `$scope.$apply()` to render the changes to the screen.

```
$(function () {
  $(window).on("scroll", function () {
    var scope = angular.element("#gif").scope();
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.varname = "mynewurl.gif";
      });
    }
    else {
      scope.$apply(function () {
        scope.varname = "images/estandar/impresoraEstandarAnimada.gif'";
      });
    }
  });
});
```

## EDIT

After you posted your updated code, I can see that you are putting all of you jQuery code inside of your angular controller. Your $(function () {...}); should be **outside** of your angular controller.

Comment: I need the value of the scrollTop... if I use () It won't give me any number therefore the if condition will never happen

Comment: @Caro My apologies, I made the assumption that your "vistaEstandar" variable was a jQuery object, not a vanilla JS DOM node. With that being the case, yes, scrollTop is the correct way to get the number

Comment: I know you are right, but for some reason,  if I put it outside of my controller,  some functions would stop functioning. For example, I can't scroll, It behaves funny with the whole Angular thing. I am continuing this work, haven't worked with angular so... I can only get it to work inside the controller

Comment: this belongs in a directive

Comment: @charlietfl I agree, but OP asked how to do it from jQuery, so that's what I showed how to do

Comment: That doesn't mean it can't be done in a directive using jQuery. Best practices should also be considered beyond just what OP asks

Answer (score 0):

when using angular js, it's a good practice to try avoiding jQuery.

The simplest answer would be, you would need to create a controller and assign it to your div.

and in your controller you can bind the scroll event to $document (document object of javascript) or $window (window object of javascript). Below is the sample code.

```
angular.module('abc',[])
     .controller('abcController', ['$scope','$window',function($scope,$window){
    angular.element($window).on('scroll',function(){
        // To access scrollX use $window.scrollX
        if($window.scrollY > 100){
           $scope.varname = 'someurl';// set varname to some url
           $scope.$apply();// this is to run the angular digest cycle, in short refreshing your div
        }

    });
}]);
```

In your Html:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 mitad" ng-controller="abcController" ng-init="varname='images/estandar/impresoraEstandarAnimada.gif'" id="seccion3B">
    <img ng-src="{{varname}}" id="gif">
</div>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: @Caro, please find my code to check how to get scrollTop or scrollY, the $window object has all the atributes you would need.

Comment: need to use `bind()` instead of `on()` if not planning to use jQuery. jQlite doesn't have `on()`. Also this belongs in  directive

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element, please check the documentation, jqlite supports on() method